# How to insert into nest document using mongoose post has many comments , comment has many replies

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

My `posts` Document has the following structure:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d9df11b0e0a6e032bf3117f"),
    "body" : "Sample content post.",
    "date" : ISODate("2019-10-07T11:02:40.126Z"),
    "comments" : [            
        {
            "comment" : "comment on post",
            "_id" : ObjectId("5d9df46e0e0a6e032bf31182"),
            "replies" : [
                { 
                    "reply" : "reply to comment ",
                    "_id" : ObjectId("5d9bec26301798056bb07ab5")
                },
                      ]
        }, 
    ],

}
```

I want to add a new `reply` to a specific `post` and `comments` of this request data `{data: req.body}`

```
{
  "data": {
    "id_post": "5d9df11b0e0a6e032bf3117f",
    "id_comment": "5d9df46e0e0a6e032bf31182",
    "new_reply": "Another new reply to comment"
  }
}
```

I am using nodejs/express/mongoose, can you help to guide how should I add a new reply.

```
   router.post("/saveReply", function(req, res, next){
     const query = Post.findById(req.body.id_post);
     const updatePost = async () => {
      try {
          await Post.updateOne(
              {
                  "_id": req.body.id_post,
                  "comments._id": req.body.id_comment
              },
              {
                  "$push": {
                      "comments.$.replies": {
                          "reply": req.body.reply,
                      }
                  }
              },
          );
      }
      catch (error) {
          console.log('', error);
      }
  };

  updatePost().then(() => console.log('✅Post updated successfully!'));

});
```

Comment: What error did you get?

Comment: the data is not save into data , it tell that cannot load the resource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try:**

```
const PostSchema = new Schema({
    body: { type: String, required: true },
    date: { type: String, required: true },
    comments: { type: Array, required: true }
});

/**
Interfaces
**/

interface IPost {
    body: string,
    date: Date,
    comments: IComment[]
}

interface IReply {
    reply: string
}

interface IComment {
    comment: string
    replies: IReply[]
}

interface IPostDocument extends Document, IPost {
    body: string,
    date: Date,
    comments: IComment[]
}

/**
Test ID's
**/
const postID = ObjectId("5d9df11b0e0a6e032bf3117f");
const commentID = ObjectId("5d9df46e0e0a6e032bf31182");
const replyID = ObjectId("5d9bec26301798056bb07ab5");

/**
New post
**/

const post: any = {
    _id: postID,
    body: "New post.",
    date: new Date(),
    comments: [{
        _id: commentID,
        comment: "New comment",
        replies: [
            {
                _id: replyID,
                reply: "New reply"
            }
        ]
    }]
}

/**
Model
**/

const PostModel = model('Post', PostSchema);

/**
Document
**/

const DemoPost = new PostModel(post);

// Demo

const query = PostModel.findById(postID);

query
.then((post) => {
    if (!post) {
        PostModel.create(DemoPost)
            .then(() => {
                console.log('✅New post created! Run the server again to update the post ');
                process.exit(0);
            })
            .catch(error => console.log('', error))
    } else {
        const updatePost = async () => {
            try {
                await PostModel.updateOne(
                    {
                        "_id": postID,
                        "comments._id": commentID
                    },
                    {
                        "$push": {
                            "comments.$.replies": {
                                "reply": "Another new reply",
                            }
                        }
                    },

                );
            }
            catch (error) {
                console.log('', error);
            }
        };

        updatePost().then(() => console.log('✅Post updated successfully!'));
    }
})
.catch(error => console.log('', error));
```

**Note:** If you use `$addToSet`, the replies array will not accept duplicates, you can get around this by using `$push`

I hope this helps, if you have any issues, I'll happily push the code to GitHub for you to test

Comment: can help to update question, and one more thing `post` is alway exist so no need to check , because what I am trying to do is to add the reply under comment

Comment: Yeah, you only need to be concerned with the updatePost() function for your actual app.  The extra code was so that I could simulate your problem.

I'm glad I could help 

Answer (score 2):

you can use `update` operation and `positional` `$` operator to accomplish this use case.

Example :

**app.js** add `mongoose` connection

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const dbURI = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/post'

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

mongoose.connection.openUri(config.dbURI);

mongoose.connection.on('connecting', () => {
    console.log('connecting to MongoDB...');
});

mongoose.connection.on('connected', () => {
    console.log('Mongoose default connection open to ' + config.dbURI);
});

mongoose.connection.on('error', (err) => {
    console.log('Mongoose default connection error: ' + err);
});

mongoose.connection.on('disconnected', () => {
    console.log('Mongoose default connection disconnected');
    mongoose.connect(dbURI, {server: {auto_reconnect: true}});
});
```

**post.js** Model file

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const ObjectId = Schema.ObjectId;

let postSchema = new Schema({
        body: String,
        date:Date,
        comments : Array
    }
);


let postCollection = mongoose.model('posts', postSchema);

module.exports = postCollection;
```

In **API**

```
let post = require('post-model-file');


let addReply = async ()=>{

  try{
       await post.update(
             {
               "_id" : ObjectId("5d9df11b0e0a6e032bf3117f"),
               "comments._id" :ObjectId("5d9df46e0e0a6e032bf31182") 
             },
            {
            "$addToSet" : { 
                "comments.$.replies" : {
                            "reply" : "reply to comment ",
                            "_id" : ObjectId("5d9bec26301798056bb07ac5")
                               }
                          }
            }
    );
}
catch(e){

console.error(e)
}
}
```

For more info check https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/

Comment: what is the Model?

Comment: An instance of a model is called a document. , for more check https://mongoosejs.com/docs/models.html , Also I have updated the answer , included the model definition

Comment: can you check my update, by follow your guideline .